# Facebook graph api images from a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

im fetching images from my own page with the following fql.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?fields=feed.limit(10).fields(shares,picture,full_picture,link,source,status_type,caption)&access_token=mytoken

everything was alright,but recently what i see is,facebook changed the url type of the picture,and it was sending small picture before,but i could have changed the _s with _n at the end of the image and could have got the large size of the image.

but right now the url they are sending is,

[https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/10565061_1121057767934438_7658962696051266848_n.jpg?oh=989ec5f139a590853c1c6469dc88daff&oe=5443BE9D&**gda**=1412917592_2176c5a44f8f2f1309d9e60d80f3e6b9](https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/10565061_1121057767934438_7658962696051266848_n.jpg?oh=989ec5f139a590853c1c6469dc88daff&oe=5443BE9D&__gda__=1412917592_2176c5a44f8f2f1309d9e60d80f3e6b9)

so my qus is,how can i get the large image size from this query or if the query needs to be changed,what would it be/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the _n to _o and remove this part from the link /v/t1.0-9/

This will give you the original image :)

[https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/10565061_1121057767934438_7658962696051266848_n.jpg?oh=989ec5f139a590853c1c6469dc88daff&oe=5443BE9D&**gda**=1412917592_2176c5a44f8f2f1309d9e60d80f3e6b9](https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/10565061_1121057767934438_7658962696051266848_n.jpg?oh=989ec5f139a590853c1c6469dc88daff&oe=5443BE9D&__gda__=1412917592_2176c5a44f8f2f1309d9e60d80f3e6b9)

Comment: Thanks ,but is it consistent?

i mean why did facebook changed the url link? did they announced the check?

i had no idea they changed the link,when i saw the images looks very bad in my app,then i went to see the problem and found this.

Comment: I don't think they announced it as both _n to _o and the new way are hacks and should be treated as such (this is my personal opinion - and I am not sure if it is correct). I also believe that the change came because of the changes to the links, apps will not recieve the user ID anymore - they will recieve a new ID so that each app has a different user id for the same user (also, not checked fact, just something I read on the side :D ) still, the hack works for now ;)